# jQuery ajax request response is empty in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

I'm doing the following ajax call:

```
//exif loader
function LoadExif(cImage) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:62414/Default1.aspx/GetImageExif",
        data: "{iCurrentImage:" + cImage + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        error: ajaxFailed,
        success: function (data, status) {
            var sStr = '';
            for (var count in data.d) {
                sStr = sStr + data.d[count];
            };
            alert(sStr);              
        }
    });
};
```

In Firefox the request works really fine. When I try to run the code in Internet Explorer, the response is empty.

Here is the webmethod witch is called:

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Shared Function GetImageExif(ByVal iCurrentImage As Integer) As String
    Dim sbTable As New StringBuilder
    sbTable.AppendLine("<table>")
    sbTable.AppendLine("<tr>")
    sbTable.AppendLine("<td>Name</td><td>" & gGallery.Images(iCurrentImage).File.Name & "</td>")
    sbTable.AppendLine("</tr>")
    sbTable.AppendLine("</table>")
    Return sbTable.ToString
End Function
```

Any ideas?

Jan

Comment: Did you make sure your WebMethod is being executed when you're using IE? The problem could be with the AJAX call. I seem to recall an issue with a certain version of jQuery in IE where AJAX calls won't fire under certain security settings. The exact details escape me.

Comment: I've been struggling with exactly this issue...unfortunately I didn't found a good solution so I'm gonna watch this thread :)

Comment: Is this a cross domain request?  If so, you need to look into jsonp.  If it is cross domain I'll dig up an example for you.

Comment: When you have `alert(data);` what do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you have alert(data); what do you see?

Thanks for this hint. This was the issue. I've copied the code from another of my projects.

```
alert(data.d);
```

... works in both browsers. Thanks for the quick answers.

Jan

Comment: Sorry Jan, not sure what's going on - care to explain for the sake of others with such problem?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with ASP.NET 3.5 MS introduced a security feature where they encapsulate any JSON response in a parent object ("d").

Doing this helps against a XSS vulnerability (described here: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx)

That's the reason why it exists.

Here's how to handle it, if you code against multiple versions of ASP.NET, you can simply use the following check in your success function to detect it's existence:

```
if (data.hasOwnProperty('d'))
  //use data.d in your code;
else
  //use data in your code
```

As for why Firefox handles it appropriately and IE8 does not, I would assume it has something to do how each parses the JSON object.